# Geb - How to remove attribute in Geb

Tags: geb

I want to set value for a datepicker, it has attribute 'readonly'. I tried `removeAttr()` to remove the attribute, but got error like this:

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.removeAttr() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [readonly]

How can I remove an attribute in Geb?

Souce code:

```
<input ng-show="!date" class="ui-form-control ng-isolate-scope" name="date" placeholder="StartTime" ui-datepicker-trigger="" selected-date="date" readonly="readonly" type="text">
```

my geb code:

```
$('input', placeholder: 'StartTime').removeAttr('readonly')
```

Thanks all

Comment: Use following code to resolve the issue:  js.exec("document.getElementsByClassName('ui-form-control ng-isolate-scope')[0].removeAttribute('readonly')")

Comment: If the attribute is read-only and you modify it, what kind of test is that? You are testing something a user cannot do on the page. I think it sounds rather pointless. Try concentrating on testing actual user behaviour instead of hacking the page. Or do you use Geb as a browser automation and page hacking tool rather than as a testing tool? In this case I kind of understand the question, even if this is not what Geb was invented for.

Comment: kriegaex， actually I can't get elements(date, month) of the datepicker(angular) even using xpath, so I want to set the value for the datepicker directly. But it seems like it only accepts the value you click on. I still don't find a way to set value for datepicker

Comment: Well, you just said it: click on the date picker. Is it somewhere on the web so I can see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the OP said it was an AngularJS datepicker and I never had any contact with Angular, myself not being a front-end guy, I wanted to learn something and now I am sharing it with you, for whatever it is worth.

Here is a Geb test which does not use any JS, but gathers information from and interacts with the Angular datepicker purely by means of Geb or Selenium. The test shows how to

1. get the currently selected date from the datepicker's text field via `myNavigator.singleElement().getAttribute("value")` (also works for inactive controls),
2. get the currently selected date by opening the datepicker and finding the highlighted date in the calendar (only works for active controls, of course),
3. rather tediously interact with the datepicker, selecting the current year's Xmas Day (Dec-25) by

   - opening the datepicker,
   - clicking on the current month in order to open the month of year selector,
   - clicking on December, effectively closing the month selector again,
   - clicking on day 25, effectively closing the datepicker again,
   - finally checking whether the right date was set by reading the text label just like in example #1.

**Page:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import geb.Page
import geb.navigator.Navigator

import java.time.Month
import java.time.format.TextStyle

import static java.util.Calendar.*

class DatePickerPage extends Page {
  static url = "https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/demo/datepicker"
  static at = { heading == "Datepicker" }
  static now = new GregorianCalendar()

  static content = {
    heading { $("h2 > span.md-breadcrumb-page.ng-binding").text() }
    datePickerButtons { $("md-datepicker > button") }
    datePickerInputFields { $(".md-datepicker-input") }
    activeDatePicker(required: false) { $(".md-datepicker-calendar-pane.md-pane-open") }
    selectedDate { activeDatePicker.$(".md-calendar-selected-date") }
    currentMonthLabel {
      activeDatePicker
        .$("td.md-calendar-month-label", text: "${getMonthShort(now)} ${now.get(YEAR)}")
    }
    selectedMonth(required: false) { $("td.md-calendar-selected-date") }
  }

  String getDatePickerValue(Navigator datePickerInputField) {
    datePickerInputField.singleElement().getAttribute("value")
  }

  Navigator getMonthLabel(Calendar calendar) {
    $(".md-calendar-month-label", text: "${calendar.get(YEAR)}").closest("tbody")
      .$("span", text: getMonthShort(calendar)).closest("td")
  }

  Navigator getDayOfMonthLabel(Calendar calendar) {
    activeDatePicker
      .$(".md-calendar-month-label", text: "${getMonthShort(calendar)} ${calendar.get(YEAR)}")
      .closest("tbody")
      .$("span", text: "${calendar.get(DAY_OF_MONTH)}")
      .closest("td")
  }

  String getMonthShort(Calendar calendar) {
    Month
      .of(calendar.get(MONTH) + 1)
      .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("en"))
      .substring(0, 3)
  }
}
```

**Test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import geb.module.FormElement
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import spock.lang.Unroll

import static java.util.Calendar.*

class DatePickerIT extends GebReportingSpec {
  def now = new GregorianCalendar()
  def xmas = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(YEAR), 12 - 1, 25)

  @Unroll
  def "Get selected date from Angular date label"() {
    when: "a date picker on the Angular demo page is chosen"
    DatePickerPage page = to DatePickerPage
    def datePickerInputField = page.datePickerInputFields[datePickerIndex]

    then: "that date picker instance is (in-)active as expected"
    datePickerInputField.module(FormElement).enabled == isEnabled

    when: "the active date is read from the date picker's text input field"
    String activeDateString = page.getDatePickerValue(datePickerInputField)
    String todayString = "${now.get(MONTH) + 1}/${now.get(DAY_OF_MONTH)}/${now.get(YEAR)}"

    then: "it is today"
    todayString == activeDateString

    where:
    datePickerIndex << [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    isEnabled << [true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
  }

  @Unroll
  def "Get selected date from opened Angular date picker"() {
    when: "a date picker on the Angular demo page is chosen"
    DatePickerPage page = to DatePickerPage
    def datePickerButton = page.datePickerButtons[datePickerIndex]

    then: "that date picker instance is active (not greyed out)"
    datePickerButton.module(FormElement).enabled

    when: "the calendar button for the date picker is clicked"
    datePickerButton.click()

    then: "the date picker pop-up opens, displaying the current month"
    waitFor 3, { page.activeDatePicker.displayed }

    when: "the active date's timestamp is read from the highlighted day in the calendar"
    def selectedDateMillis = page.selectedDate.attr("data-timestamp") as long
    def sinceMidnightMillis = now.getTimeInMillis() - selectedDateMillis

    then: "it is today"
    sinceMidnightMillis >= 0
    sinceMidnightMillis < 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    where:
    datePickerIndex << [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  }

  def "Set date in Angular date picker"() {
    when: "the first date picker's calendar button on the Angular demo page is clicked"
    DatePickerPage page = to DatePickerPage
    page.datePickerButtons[0].click()

    then: "the date picker pop-up opens, displaying the current month"
    waitFor 3, { page.activeDatePicker.displayed }

    when: "the current month label is clicked"
    page.currentMonthLabel.click()

    then: "the month selection page opens"
    waitFor 3, { page.selectedMonth.displayed }
    page.selectedMonth.text() == page.getMonthShort(now)

    when: "December for the current year is selected"
    page.getMonthLabel(xmas).click()

    then: "the month selection page closes again"
    waitFor 3, { !page.selectedMonth.displayed }

    when: "Xmas Day (25) is selected on the month calendar"
    page.getDayOfMonthLabel(xmas).click()

    then: "the date picker pop-up closes again"
    waitFor 3, { !page.activeDatePicker.displayed }

    when: "the active date is read from the date picker's text input field"
    String activeDateString = page.getDatePickerValue(page.datePickerInputFields[0])
    String xmasDayString = "${xmas.get(MONTH) + 1}/${xmas.get(DAY_OF_MONTH)}/${xmas.get(YEAR)}"

    then: "it is Xmas Day of the current year"
    xmasDayString == activeDateString
  }

}
```

The advantage of this approach is obvious: You only interact with the page in a way the user would/could also do, thus avoiding to manipulate the page in a way impossible for a user (which would result in a bad test).

**Update:** I refactored the code into using a page object.

Comment: Update: I refactored the code into using a page object.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Your script extremely guides me to fix my issues. Now I interact with page as the users do to instead of editing elements

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver and thus Geb do not allow you to modify the DOM directly.

You will need to use javascript via [the js object](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#js-object) to do that which will be even easier if your page has jQuery loaded into it thanks to [Geb's jQuery integration](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#jquery-integration).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if my page does't have JQuery loaded, how can I remove readonly or send value for the element?

Comment: I'd use javascript's [`Element.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've resolved the problem, please see my answer in the below

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to resolve the issue:

```java
js.exec(
  "document.getElementsByClassName('ui-form-control ng-isolate-scope')[0]" + 
  ".removeAttribute('readonly')"
)
```